# Ktor Resources validation plugin

Tags: ktor

I've a Ktor server application using the [Resources](https://ktor.io/docs/type-safe-routing.html) plugin for type-safe routing. Now I want to create a custom plugin to validate the resource instance.
But I can't figure what is the correct phase for intercepting the pipeline.

A custom "Validation Phase" inserted before the call phase seems to be executed to early as the Resource instance is not yet added to the ApplicationCall attributes. I do not really understand why thats the case, because the decoding of the Resource instance should by done in the Plugins phase? Found the following in io.ktor.server.resources.Routing:

```kt
public fun <T : Any> Route.handle(
    serializer: KSerializer<T>,
    body: suspend PipelineContext<Unit, ApplicationCall>.(T) -> Unit
) {
    intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Plugins) {
        val resources = application.plugin(Resources)
        try {
            val resource = resources.resourcesFormat.decodeFromParameters(serializer, call.parameters)
            call.attributes.put(ResourceInstanceKey, resource)
        } catch (cause: Throwable) {
            throw BadRequestException("Can't transform call to resource", cause)
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

If I add my custom validation phase after the call phase it's executed to late, after the route handler.

Here some example code...

Route and Resource:

```kt
fun Route.exampleRouting() {

    get<ExampleResource> { example ->
        println("Validated value: ${example.somevalue}")
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    }
}


fun Application.registerExampleRoutes() {
    routing {
        exampleRouting()
    }
}

@Serializable
@Resource("/example")
class ExampleResource(val somevalue: String)
```

Custom validation plugin:

```kt
val ResourcesValidation = createApplicationPlugin("ResourcesValidation") {

    on(ValidationHook) { call ->
        val resourceInstanceKey =
            call.attributes.allKeys.filterIsInstance<AttributeKey<Any>>().find { it.name == "ResourceInstance" }

        // PROBLEM: resourceInstanceKey is null here, ResourceInstance not yet added to call attributes

        resourceInstanceKey?.let {
            val resourceInstance = call.attributes[resourceInstanceKey]
            // Validate resource instance here...
            println("validated")
        }
    }
}

object ValidationHook : Hook<suspend (ApplicationCall) -> Unit> {

    val ValidationPhase: PipelinePhase = PipelinePhase("Validation")

    override fun install(
        pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline,
        handler: suspend (ApplicationCall) -> Unit
    ) {
        pipeline.insertPhaseBefore(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call, ValidationPhase)
        pipeline.intercept(ValidationPhase) { handler(call) }
    }
}
```

And of cause installing the plugin and registering the routes in the Application:

```kt
fun Application.module() {
    ...
    install(ResourcesValidation)
    ...
    registerExampleRoutes()
    ...
}
```

I've tried the same with the [Base API](https://ktor.io/docs/custom-plugins-base-api.html#create-companion) but same result.

So..is there any way to intercept the pipeline at the right time to validate the Resource instance before the route handler is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you can write a `RouteScopedPlugin` and install it into the routing because a resource instance is put into the call attributes while interception of a route's call pipeline, not an application's pipeline.

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 4444) {
        install(Resources)

        routing {
            install(ResourcesValidation)

            get<ExampleResource> { example ->
                println("Validated value: ${example.somevalue}")
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}

val ResourcesValidation = createRouteScopedPlugin("ResourcesValidation") {

    on(ValidationHook) { call ->
        try {
            val resourceInstance = call.attributes[AttributeKey("ResourceInstance")]
            println("validated")
        } catch (_: IllegalStateException) {
            // attribute not found
        }
    }
}

object ValidationHook : Hook<suspend (ApplicationCall) -> Unit> {

    val ValidationPhase: PipelinePhase = PipelinePhase("Validation")

    override fun install(
        pipeline: ApplicationCallPipeline,
        handler: suspend (ApplicationCall) -> Unit
    ) {
        pipeline.insertPhaseAfter(ApplicationCallPipeline.Plugins, ValidationPhase)
        pipeline.intercept(ValidationPhase) { handler(call) }
    }
}
```

Comment: But just for my understanding, how is the connection between the application pipeline and the route's pipeline? Is there any documentation about that, didn't find anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no documentation about that. Routing is a call pipeline in itself and it's independent of an application's call pipeline. Routes' handlers are executed in the `Call` phase of the application's pipeline.